# Selection expression using GJSON syntax, as in the example with jq

Tags: json, go, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am trying to configure the HTTP input plugin using Telegraf, but I need to select certain metrics using the select expression and write them to a specific Influxdb database. I know how to select using jq, but I can't do it using a GJSON request.

My output look like this:

```json
  [
      {
        "properties": {
          "headers": {
            "database": "telegraf"
          },
          "content_type": "text/plain"
        },
        "payload": "net,cluster_id=cluster01,dc=dc02,host=specific_host01,instance=instance-00107205 network_write_packets=15100740,network_write_drops=0 1628285530000000000\n",
        "payload_encoding": "string"
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "headers": {
            "database": "stats"
          },
          "content_type": "text/plain"
        },
        "payload": "dsk_stats,Region=Q3,host=specific_host01 disk_usage=8.344534641 1628285530000000000\n",
        "payload_encoding": "string"
      }
  ]
```

For choosing metrics by stats I'm using jq:

```bash
    curl -s -H "content-type:application/json" localhost:8080 |jq '.[] | select(.properties.headers.database=="stats") | "\(.payload)"
    dsk_stats,Region=Q3,host=specific_host01 disk_usage=8.344534641 1628285530000000000\n
```

Is it possible to make such json selection using the GJSON syntax?

Comment: this isn't well fromated json.

Comment: til: about gjson. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
#(properties.headers.database=="stats").payload
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7bXY6F2MQeZ